# URL Page redirect Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am making an application similar to twitter. On each persons profile page there is an option for the current logged in user to follow the person who's profile page they are viewing. I have a follow/unfollow button and it works, however, once clicked it redirects to an error page, but if you go back and refresh you can see that if you were following them you are now unfollowing them. So my question is once the button is clicked how do I get it to redirect to the same page?

**Here is the error I get:**

_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not Profile ...

/home/skybluep/thesite/panda/twitter/views.py in follow

65 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile))

**My Views:**

```
@login_required
def follow(request, username): 
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    user_profile.following.add(profile)
    user_profile.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile))

@login_required
def unfollow(request, username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    user_profile.following.remove(profile)
    user_profile.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile))
```

**My App URLS**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='twitterindex'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<username>\w+)/newpost/$', views.post, name='newpost'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<username>\w+)/follow', views.follow, name='follow'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<username>\w+)/unfollow', views.unfollow, name='unfollow'),

)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear enough, you should do:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args=(profile.user.username,) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile.user.username))`. also you don't need `user_profile.save()`

Better method:

```
@login_required
def follow(request, username): 
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    user_profile.following.add(profile)        
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile.user.username))

@login_required
def unfollow(request, username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    user_profile.following.remove(profile)    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitterindex:detail', args = profile.user.username))
```